# How to deal with a modal shown in a guard

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I have a guard implemented like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if (this.authService.isCustomer) {
      return true;
    }
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(SigninModalComponent, {
      data: {
        errorMessage: this.authService.isLoggedIn ?
          'You don\t have access to this page, please use an appropriate account' :
          'Please authenticate to access this page'
      }
    });

    return dialog.afterClosed().pipe(
      map(() => {
        return this.authService.isCustomer;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

When I type an unauthorized route in my browser's address bar, the server-side rendering shows an inert modal, then when the client-side takes over, another working modal is shown where I can successfully authenticate and access the requested route.

The problem is that the server-side rendered modal never disappears...

Is there a clean solution to this problem that wouldn't imply not to show the modal on server side?

Comment: Does the `unauthorized route` exist in client side routing configuration? If yes, how is server side rendering getting triggered? If not, route guard shouldn't get executed. Let me know if I'm missing something

Comment: @planet_hunter of course the routes exist in both server and client side. I don't get your point.

Comment: Alright, can you specify the `unauthorized route` URL you typed in browser's window?

Answer (score 0):

I would use DI to help you with this one. I utilized the [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) sample from their website to create an example.

First create a token:
`app/tokens.ts`

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export let RENDERED_BY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('renderedBy');
```

Update the `app.module.ts` to use this token to provide a value through the DI container:

```
import { RENDERED_BY_TOKEN } from './tokens';
@NgModule({
.
.
.
providers: [
  .,
  .,
  { provide: RENDERED_BY_TOKEN, useValue: 'client' }
],
.
.
.
export class AppModule { }
```

Update the `app.server.module.ts` to use this token to provide a value through the DI container:

```
import { RENDERED_BY_TOKEN } from './tokens';
@NgModule({
.
.
.
providers: [
  .,
  .,
  { provide: RENDERED_BY_TOKEN, useValue: 'server' }
],
.
.
.
export class AppServerModule { }
```

Then elsewhere in your code(I used a component, but you would put this in your route guard), inject the value utilizing that token:

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { RENDERED_BY_TOKEN } from './tokens';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  renderedBy;

  constructor(@Inject(RENDERED_BY_TOKEN) val: string) {
    this.renderedBy = val;
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h5>{{renderedBy}}</h5>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
  <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-messages></app-messages>
```

If you run this, you will see the `h5` element update from 'server' to 'client' showing that its working. You could utilize this value in your guard in an if statement to not show that dialog on the server render.

**UPDATE**

In going through this write-up, I noticed an easier way. It seems as though Angular itself provides you this information without the need for a custom token.

In the Guard you can update it with the following:

```
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
  const isServer = !isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
}
```

**UPDATE2**

Given the clarification to the question, the only way I've been able to accomplish this seems a little less than ideal, but is the only thing I've found to work thus far.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.cdk-overlay-container').forEach(dialog => dialog.remove());
```

For reference, all of my work for this answer is in a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/universal).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that I could conditionally load the server modal. My question is about showing the server-side modal and hiding it when client side takes over.

Comment: although this solution doesn't suit me, I'll award you the bounty for your research effort if there's still no other answer when the bounty expires

Comment: What about the solution isn't satisfactory? Maybe there is something else that could be done to make it work for your scenario.

Comment: I just mean that like you said, the solution is "less than ideal", we're not supposed to use Javascript's API directly in Angular

Comment: Understood. I would have thought that as well. As with my comment to the other answer and the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-in-action) though, it seems in this instance it is required.